# i need to compare a date using check_in_range() function

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp-3.0

I need that when I add a reservation according to the date that the user chooses, my function add () validates me if on this date there is no previous reservation ... I have a reservation table that has field FROM (ymd) and HASTA ( Ymd) then I thought I'd use the check_in_range function ($ start_date, $ end_date, $ date_to_valuate)
And this is what I try to do but it blocks me and now I'm lost this is my function add () in my reservationscontroller.php

```
public function add()
{
    $reserva = $this->Reservas->newEntity();
    $res = 'SELECT desde,hasta FROM reservas';
    $arr = $this->Reservas->ExQuery($res);

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $reserva = $this->Reservas->patchEntity($reserva, $this->request->getData());
        if($arr==null){
           // $this->log('keria salvar1', LOG_DEBUG);
        if ($this->Reservas->save($reserva)) {
            //$this->log('salvas con arreglo vacio', LOG_DEBUG);
            $this->Flash->success(__('La habitación ha sido reservada.'));

            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'reservas', 'action' => 'index']);
        }}
        if($arr!=null){
          for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
                $start_date = $arr[$i]['desde'];
                $end_date = $arr[$i]['hasta'];
                $fecha_a_evaluar = date("Y-m-d");

                if ($this->check_in_range($start_date, $end_date, $fecha_a_evaluar)) {
                   // $this->log('error fecha', LOG_DEBUG);
                    $this->Flash->error(__('ya existe reserva en esa fecha'));

                } 
                    if ($this->Reservas->save($reserva)) {
                       // $this->log('salvo', LOG_DEBUG);
                        $this->Flash->success(__('La habitación ha sido reservada.'));
                        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'reservas', 'action' => 'index']);
                    }

                          }}
                          $this->Flash->error(__('La habitación no ha podido ser reservada'));
                         // $this->log('final1', LOG_DEBUG);
                    }
       // $this->Flash->error(__('La habitación no ha podido ser reservada'));
        //$this->log('final2', LOG_DEBUG);


    $habitaciones = $this->Reservas->Habitaciones->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('reserva', 'habitaciones'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['reserva']);
}
```

and in my appcontroler this is the code for the function

```
function check_in_range($start_date, $end_date, $evaluame) {
   $start_ts = strtotime($start_date);
   $end_ts = strtotime($end_date);
   $user_ts = strtotime($evaluame);
   return (($user_ts >= $start_ts) && ($user_ts <= $end_ts) && ($user_ts === $start_ts)); }
```

I'm desperate and stuck

Answer (score 0):

due to :

```
return (($user_ts >= $start_ts) && ($user_ts <= $end_ts) && ($user_ts === $start_ts)); }
```

check_in_range only return true when all three arguments (`$start_date, $end_date, $evaluame`) are equal